# How to Setup SVN for remote access

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I am new to SVN thing. I have a remote server, windows server 2003. I want my team to commit their work on server on daily basis. I am choosing SVN for this task but I dont know what i need and from where to start? How the SVN will be configured on both the server and client side? I tried to read different tutorials. Some are outdated or some links are broken etc. So please help me out by keeping things simple. Please guide me what I need on server and client.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at a [Subversion Cheat Sheet](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/misc/svn01/) on how to create a repository on your server.

```
svnadmin create d:/path_to_repository
```

Your clients must check out projects and commit code from and to this repository using the command line (see the cheat sheet for svn commands)

```
svn checkout file:///d:/repository_name/project/trunk project
```

or a client like [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/):

[image: Tortoise checkout]

References:

- [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)
- [Quick Reference (common subversion
  commands)](http://www.open.collab.net/community/subversion/articles/SvnQuickReferenceCard.html)

Answer (score 5):

My recommendation for the server to keep it super simple is Visual SVN Server;
http://www.visualsvn.com
This option provides a connection to the repositories over https. The repositories can be created via a gui installed as a part of the setup package.

For the client. You really only need to install TortoiseSVN and they can connect to the repository, once its created. 
http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org I'm not overly proficient in using Tortoise itself.

If you are using Visual Studio for a nominal fee (there is a 30 day trial) each developer can get a licence of VisualSVN. Which is a good solution for Visual Studio 2005 up to 2010. It's not suitable for other development tools though.